# Is there a way to get the X,Y from a feature class?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, features

I currently have an instance of a selected feature class, and I want to be able to get the midpoint X,Y (if its polygon) or the X,Y (if its IPoint) of the feature from the layer, is there some build in GIS method that I can achieve that easily?

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By "midpoint" I'm assuming you're asking about a centroid.

For polygons, you'll want to cast it to an [IArea](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IArea_Interface/002m00000094000000/) object (see link for example), and then access the Centroid property.  For points, you can simply get the X/Y property of the [IPoint](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IPoint_Interface/002m0000026v000000/) object.  To get the feature, you can use various [IFeatureClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureClass_Interface/0025000002qs000000/) methods such as GetFeature to access it using the ObjectID, or Search to find a feature using a Query (spatial or text).

Comment: Hi Sasa, I tried to use your method, I have my IFeature, before, I casted it to IEnvelope and used minX + width/2, to get the center, when I casted my IFeature.Shape(IPolygon) to IArea, ((IArea)IFeature.Shape).Centroid, it returns me 0s, but my envelope has the minX and minY set properly, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head now, but try the QueryCentroid() method instead.  Create a new IPoint and pass it to the QueryCentroid() method, then check the X/Y of the point after the call.  It should contain the correct values.  If not, check the Area property of IArea, see if it gets populated properly (again, it should).

Comment: Remember that a centroid does not have to fall inside a polygon. IArea has a LabelPoint property that is guaranteed to be within the polygon.